# Hello, I would like to know how can I accept the users input from one Method and use that new stored data to print it out in another Method?

Tags: c#

```
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Program.GetSportsTeam(); //Call the void method to get SportsTeam information

         string city = GetSportsTeam(cityName); //Get the stored user input from the function
         string team = GetSportsTeam(teamName);//and store that information in new variables
         string date = GetSportsTeam(fanDate);//in order to print using the called print menthod

            Program.PrintSportsTeam(city, team, date);
      }

        static void GetSportsTeam()
        {
            //Get users Sports team info
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the city of your favorite sports team:");
            string cityName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Now enter their team name:");
            string teamName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the date roughly of when you became a fan of said sports team:");
            DateTime fanDate = System.DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

            static void PrintSportsTeam(string city, string team, string date)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} became my favorite team on: {2}", city, team, date);
        }
    }


    ***
```

> Output I am trying to get is:
>           Enter city name of your favorite sports team: New York
>           Now enter their team name: Yankees
>           Enter the date of when you became a fan of said sports team: 3/26/2020
>           New York Yankees became my favorite team on 3/26/2020

---

Comment: You can google "Scope of Variables in C#" it can help you understand what heppened in the case.

Comment: Thank You for your response. I will be sure to heed that advice.

Answer (score 1):

https://pastebin.com/WuKNnNsi

With how you've structured, you could do something like this. Its important to understand variable scopes(https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/know-scope-local-variables). So when you have something like:

```
 static void GetSportsTeam()
        {
            //Get users Sports team info
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the city of your favorite sports team:");
            string cityName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Now enter their team name:");
            string teamName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the date roughly of when you became a fan of said sports team:");
            DateTime fanDate = System.DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Your variables cityName, teamname, and fanDate wont exist outside your GetSportsTeam method. That is why i changed the method to return a string, and then we can store what the method returns in a variable.

Comment: Thank You for responding and the resource link. I realized once I changed static void GetSportsTeam() to static string GetSportsTeam() I was finally able to return the desired input from the user to the main method.

Comment: @EmptyCup nice job :)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the set define cityName, teamName and fanDate to top of your Main(){ here }